# Simulate "Enter" key when <a> link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, keystroke

My minimal form only allows 'Enter' keystrokes and I want it to behave the same way when clicking on the "Envoyer" link. I've looked around for Javascript/JQuery solutions but none worked.

**Do you know how can I "simulate" Enter keystroke on a link click?**

*Here is my site with my form*: http://raphaelmartin.olympe.in/pc/fruit.html

*The interesting part in the JS file*:

```
// pressing enter will jump to next question
        document.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( ev ) {
            var keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
            // enter
            if( keyCode === 13 ) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                self._nextQuestion();
            }
        } );
```

*Here is the A link in my HTML file*:

```
<p id="envoyer"><a id="returnkey" href="#">Envoyer</a></p>
```

Comment: That's extremely round about.

Instead of simulating the enter key, just call `self._nextQuestion()` directly in your `<a>` tag's click event handler.

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/R4mFs/)?

Comment: @chridam Thank you for your answer. I've just tested your code on a page: raphaelmartin.olympe.in/pc/marie.html but it doesn't seem to work :/ What's wrong?

Comment: @cheezburger Try register the keypress event http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/R4mFs/1/

Comment: @chridam Thank you but... it's seems even worse! http://raphaelmartin.olympe.in/pc/marie.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not assign the function to the button also?

```
$( "#returnkey" ).on( "click", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  self._nextQuestion();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. I've put your code at the end of my file though, am i doing it wrong? > http://raphaelmartin.olympe.in/pc/fruit.html

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a click event on the element once enter is pressed thus you only need one event handler

```
    //your return key link
    var ret = document.getElementById("returnkey")

    //handling key presses
    document.addEventListener( 'keydown', function(ev){ if (ev.keyCode || ev.which == 13) {
              //trigger a click event on the link if enter pressed
                ret.click(); } }, false );

    //handle the click event on the link
    ret.addEventListener( 'click', handler, false);


 function handler(ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation();
    ev.preventDefault();
   //call next question function
   //self._nextQuestion();

   alert(" you clicked me ");

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
// +++++ attach an event handler
function AttachEventHandler(X00,X01,X02,X03)
// X00 pointer of object
// X01 kind of event, String e.g. 'mouseover' (not 'onmouseover')
// X02 pointer of function of handler
//  param e for parsing an event
//      e.g.   keyDownTextField (e) 
//              {
//               var keyCode = e.keyCode;
//               //...
//              }
// X03 bubbling flag
//     true Capturing by handler
//     same value for DetachEventHandler()
{
 var X04=false;         
 X04=(X00!=null);
 if(X04){X04=(X01!=null);}
 if(X04){X04=(X02!=null);}
 if(X04){X04=(X01!='');}
 if(X04)
 {
  if(X00.attachEvent)
  {
   X04=X00.attachEvent('on'+X01,X02);
  }
  else
  {
   if(X00.addEventListener)
   {
    X00.addEventListener(X01,X02,X03);
    X04=true;
   }
   else{X04=false;}
  }
 }

 return X04;
}

// +++++ detach an event handler
function DetachEventHandler(X00,X01,X02,X03)
// X00 pointer of object
// X01 kind of event, String e.g. 'mouseover' (not 'onmouseover')
// X02 pointer of function of handler
//  param e for parsing an event
//      e.g.   keyDownTextField (e) 
//              {
//               var keyCode = e.keyCode;
//               //...
//              }
// X03 bubbling flag
//     true Capturing by handler
//     same value for AttachEventHandler()
{
 var X04=false;         
 X04=(X00!=null);
 if(X04){X04=(X01!=null);}
 if(X04){X04=(X02!=null);}
 if(X04){X04=(X01!='');}
 if(X04)
 {
  if(X00.detachEvent)
  {
   X04=X00.detachEvent('on'+X01,X02);
  }
  else
  {
   if(X00.removeEventListener)
   {
    X00.removeEventListener(X01,X02,X03);
    X04=true;
   }
   else{X04=false;}
  }
 }

 return X04;
}
```

Comment: `X00,X01,X02,X03,X04` --- o_O. Really?